# Can you set element events programmatically in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

In a Svelte project I need to create an element programmatically and I wish to set events for it. In this sample the html item 'old text' works correctly, but if I try to create an element programmatically ('new text'), it does not seem to recognise the events.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/aaee471c2b034439be652a846558be31?version=3.52.0)

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
    let image_holder_id     
    let colour = 'red';
    
    function refresh() {
        let new_text = document.getElementById('new-text')
        new_text.innerHTML = '<p on:mouseover={handleMouseOver} on:mouseout={handleMouseOut}>new text</p>'
    }
    
    function handleMouseOver(e) {
        colour = 'green';
    }
    function handleMouseOut(e) {
        colour = 'red';
    }
</script>

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill={colour}>
</svg>

<div><p on:mouseover={handleMouseOver} on:mouseout={handleMouseOut}>old text</p></div>

<button on:click={refresh}>Click</button>

<div id="new-text"></div>
```

What can I do?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you hardly (and I mean hardly), ever need to create elements manually in svelte, there is almost always a better solution. However, if you truly do need to you should just simply use the normal [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) methods such as `addEventListener`. Svelte doesn't [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the DOM APIs or anything like that, so if you are using the DOM APIs then you should just go full vanilla JS

[Event Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Example fix:

```js
function refresh() {
        let new_text = document.getElementById('new-text');
        
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.addEventListener("mouseOver", handleMouseOver);
        p.addEventListener("mouseOut", handleMouseOut);
        p.innerText = "new text";

        new_text.replaceChildren(p);
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/afce5b1a3e6c4bd4b727673394da686d?version=3.52.0)

As I said though there is a far better solution without hijacking the DOM,

```html
<script>
    let image_holder_id     
    let colour = 'red';
    let newTextShown = false;
    
    function refresh() {
        newTextShown = true;
    }
    
    function handleMouseOver(e) {
        colour = 'green';
    }
    function handleMouseOut(e) {
        colour = 'red';
    }
</script>

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill={colour}>
</svg>

<div><p on:mouseover={handleMouseOver} on:mouseout={handleMouseOut}>old text</p></div>

<button on:click={refresh}>Click</button>

<div id="new-text">
    {#if newTextShown}
        <p on:mouseover={handleMouseOver} on:mouseout={handleMouseOut}>new text</p>
    {/if}
</div>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/296ecfb0423c4b11898b293a72e56013?version=3.52.0)

Comment: "you hardly (and I mean hardly), ever need to create elements manually in svelte" Thereby hangs my problem. In the real use case the number of elements to be created is variable and unknown at compile time, do I guess I have to go for the DOM hack

Comment: @Psionman: You really probably don't. There are directives like `{#each}` for a reason.

Comment: Thnks. I'll give it some thought

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create elements like this. Svelte compiles the code, any Svelte syntax you try to use at runtime will be meaningless.

If you create elements at runtime you need to use something like [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). But you are probably doing something wrong because you generally do not have to do any of that.

If anything, you would create a separate component and instantiate it using the [client-side API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api).